# Resolve selected merge conflicts using p4merge in GIT

Tags: git, git-merge, p4merge

Is there a way to resolve selected file having conflicts using p4merge in GIT?

Lets say there are 25 conflicts and each conflict has to be resolved by each developer, if any developer runs 'git mergetool' the p4merge which is setup starts with the first conflict.
this conflict maynot be related to that developers, so am searching for a way where a dev can resolve a specific conflicted file using the p4merge tool which is invoked from Unix.

Or is there a way for GIT to show the version/commit of the $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE so that i can use this in the gui mode of p4merge to resolve the conflict.